# StringBuffer or synchronized method?

Tags: java, multithreading, stringbuilder, synchronized, stringbuffer

I have following code:

```
public class MyLogger {
   private StringBuilder logger = new StringBuilder();

   public void log(String message, String user) {
      logger.append(message);
      logger.append(user);
   }
}
```

The programmer must guarantee that a single MyLogger object works properly for a
multi-threaded system.
How must this code be changed to be thread-safe?

A. synchronize the log method

B. replace `StringBuilder` with `StringBuffer`

Please advise the best approach.

Comment: So this accumulates in logger, what is the point?

Comment: I would probably not use either, preferring a 'LogEntry' class instance that holds a copy of both strings and a command to a logger thread that waits at the end of a Blocking Queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StringBuffer` is  not enough to guarantee that the two information are always sent grouped :

```
  logger.append(message);
  logger.append(user);
```

It guarantees only that `append()` will not be invoked in a concurrent way and that so you don't risk to break the state of the `StringBuffer` object. 
You could indeed have two threads that interleave during the `log()` invocation and get these invocations :

> Thread 1 : logger.append(message);
>
> Thread 2 : logger.append(message);
>
> Thread 1 : logger.append(user);
>
> Thread 2 : logger.append(user);

This is so better :

```
  public synchronized void log(String message, String user) {
      logger.append(message);
      logger.append(user);
   }
```

You can also do the synchronization on the private `logger` object.
Which has the advantage to not allow the client of the class to lock it outside the class.

Comment: You may want to mention that synchronizing on a private object is a better choice than using `synchronized` on the method signature.

Comment: @Alvin Thompson nice advise. I added it.

Comment: Thanks @davidxxx for the nice description. Please let me know if my understandng is wrong: say,Thread 1 got the chance to perform logger.append(message); so T1 has the lock on SB object and on completion of the method execution it will release lock on SB? so T2 can perform  logger.append(message); and thus problem may arise? is this what you wanted to describe?

Comment: you are welcome. You are close,  "and on completion of the method execution it **may** release lock on".

Comment: okay. Hence problem arises when T1 releases the lock and T2 may start performing, i.e.,

    

    Thread 1 : logger.append(message);

    Thread 2 : logger.append(message);

    Thread 1 : logger.append(user);

    Thread 2 : logger.append(user);

otherwise if T1 holds the lock then it can continue with: logger.append(user); and T2 will not get a chance, so this will be like:

    

    Thread 1 : logger.append(message);

    Thread 1 : logger.append(user);

    Thread 2 : logger.append(message);

    Thread 2 : logger.append(user);

Comment: you got it. It is not deterministic. Without synchronizing the  method, even if T1 wrote the message first, you may "randomly" finish in the first or the second scenario that you described.

Answer (score 0):

Use A, because if you choose to use StringBuffer you could mess the log:
This could happen with StringBuffer (will generate wrong log):

```
logger.append(message); < Thread A
logger.append(message); < Thread B
logger.append(user);  < Thread A
logger.append(user); < Thread B
```